# sewer pipeline or sewerage pipeline

Tags: word-usage

Would one say:

The sewer pipelines are old and need to be replaced. or ...

The sewerage pipelines are old need o be replaced

additionally:

The sewer infrastructure ...

The sewerage infrastructure

any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A *[sewer](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sewer)* is

An artificial, usually underground conduit for carrying off sewage or rainwater.

so a *sewer pipeline* is a slightly redundant term, only necessary to distinguish a sewer pipeline from some other kind of sewer.

*[Sewerage](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sewerage)* is

1. A system of sewers.
2. Removal of waste materials by means of a sewer system.
3. Sewage.

so unless you have the third meaning fixed in other parts of your conversation it again seems unnecessary.

You could call it a *[sewage](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sewage)* pipe

> Liquid and solid waste carried off in sewers or drains.

in the same way as you might have a water pipe or a gas pipe. *Infrastructure* is mush word that serves no purpose here. I myself would just go with *sewer*:-

> The *sewers* are old and need replacing.

Answer (score 1):

A *sewer* is an underground channel for taking away waste water. So a *sewer pipeline* is an underground pipeline that serves as a sewer (or perhaps a pipe that connects directly to the sewer).

*Sewerage* is the whole drainage system that uses *sewers*. So you never need to use the word *infrastructure*; you can just say *sewerage*. A *sewerage pipeline* can be any part of the sewerage system, so it is more general than *sewer pipeline*.

Comment: Could you substantiate this with a reference? I could not find anything using the "usual suspects".

Comment: No, I can't, other than the dictionary definitions of *sewer* and *sewerage*. But my answer is entirely consistent with the normal patterns of English usage.

Comment: From what I've seen in leaflets trying to get us to take out additional insurance, a 'drain' connects from our house to a 'main drain', and this in turn connects to the local 'sewer'. How standard this terminology is, I don't know.